# TSQL how to use if else in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a report, the report will have parameter for the user to select

```
-IsApprovedDate
-IsCatcheDate
```

I would like to know how to used the `if else` in the where clause.

Example if the user selects IsApprovedDate the report will lookup based on approved Date else will lookup based on catch date. In my query I will get top10 fish size base on award order weight here is my query.

```
  ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        select  Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY c.trophyCatchCertificateTypeId order by c.catchWeight desc ) as rnk     
                ,c.id,c.customerId, Cust.firstName + ' '+Cust.lastName as CustomerName 
                ,CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10),catchWeightPoundsComponent)+'.'+CONVERT(varchar(10),catchWeightOuncesComponent) as  numeric(6,2) ) WLBS
                ,c.catchGirth,c.catchLength,ct.description county          
               ,t.description award--
               ,c.trophyCatchCertificateTypeId  
               ,s.specificSpecies--
               ,c.speciesId   

         from Catches c             
         INNER JOIN TrophyCatchCertificateTypes t on c.trophyCatchCertificateTypeId = t.id
         INNER JOIN Species s on c.speciesId = s.id
         INNER JOIN Counties ct on c.countyId = ct.id
         INNER JOIN Customers Cust on c.customerId = cust.id
         Where c.bigCatchCertificateTypeId is not null   
               and  c.catchStatusId =1 
         and c.speciesId =1 and c.isTrophyCatch =1 
         and c.catchDate >= @startDay and c.catchDate<=@endDay

     )
    Select * from CTE c1
     Where rnk <=10
```

Comment: In SQL Server, the "IF..ELSE" is accomplished by the "CASE..WHEN..THEN..ELSE" statement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Caffe Thank you for the link its very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional logic for this:

```
where . . . and
      ((@IsApprovedDate = 1 and c.ApprovedDate >= @startDay and c.ApprovedDate <= @endDay) or
       (@IsCatchDate = 1 and c.catchDate >= @startDay and c.catchDate <= @endDay)
      )
```

EDIT:

I would actually write this as:

```
where . . . and
      ((@IsApprovedDate = 1 and c.ApprovedDate >= @startDay and c.ApprovedDate < dateadd(day, 1 @endDay) or
       (@IsCatchDate = 1 and c.catchDate >= @startDay and c.catchDate < dateadd(day, 1, @endDay))
      )
```

This is a safer construct because it work when the date values have times and when they do not.

Comment: you can also use the  `between` to compare both dates as           `c.catchDate between @startDay and @endDay`

Comment: @Smog . . . I discourage people from using `between` for dates.  It tends to lead to problems when the dates have time components.

Comment: you can also include your `dateadd(day, 1, @endDay)` to the `between` clause

Comment: @Smog . . . Notice the `<` instead of `<=`.  The purpose here is to make the code safe even when the "date" has a time component.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer. I am appreciated all your help its save me alot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Performance will be much better if you build the WHERE clause dynamically in your code and then execute it.

Comment: agree with you please please visit this for better understand @qwerty12579 answer

Comment: Thank you qwerty13579, Neeraj i am sure visiting your site.